# (Vue js and firebase real time database) How can users that not is logged send data to the firebase with rules

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hello I have a firebase database with rules that only auth users can write and the users that not is logged in can only read. But I have a FAQ page and I want that all of the users have access to write only for the FAQ page.
How can I do that?

**This is my firebase rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

I don't want that the users that not is logged in can write a form from a other page.
But I want only that all the users that can write on the FAQ page.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want that all of the users have access to write only for the FAQ page"?  Database rules don't affect web pages, they affect nodes in the database.  You will need to figure out which node you want people to write to.

Comment: Normally only the users that logged in can only post something, but I want that the users that not is logged in have access to post only on the FAQ page.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, security rules don't protect pages, they protect database data.